# How can we know what cos(-75) is?

Tags: trigonometry

We need to prove it using the sum and difference formula. We also need to use special triangles. how? I've tried doing cos(a-b) but I did cos(-30)cos(-75)

Comment: I'll betcha mean in degrees . . .

Answer (score 8):

$$\cos(-75^\circ)=\cos(75^\circ)=\cos(45^\circ+30^\circ)=\cos(45^\circ)\cos(30^\circ)-\sin(45^\circ)\sin(30^\circ)$$
Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

$\cos(-75)=\cos(75)=\cos(45+30)=\cos (30)\cos(45)-\sin(30)\sin(45)$

Comment: Hi I got square root of 6 - square root of 2 all over 4. How does that help me prove what cos(-75)? I want to to prove it so I can impress my teacher. :)

Comment: Your result is correct! Good work.  That means that you have found the cosine of $-75$.

Answer (score 1):

$\cos 75^\circ=x>0$, then from the double angle formula (which is technically sum and difference :D )
$$2x^2-1=\cos(150^\circ)=-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}$$
$$x=\sqrt{\frac{2-\sqrt{3}}{4}}=\frac{\sqrt{8-4\sqrt{3}}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{(\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2})^2}}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{6}-\sqrt{2}}{4}$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course cos(75) as in 75 radians can be computed using Taylor series. Note cos(24*pi+x)=1-x^2/2+x^4/4-...

Substitute 75-24*pi (about -.4) in for x to find cos(75).